# jQuery based dropdown menu not behaving when aligned to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following script which works almost perfectly:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="navigation1">icon Home</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="items">icon Default 1</div>
        <div class="items">icon Reports 1</div>
        <div class="items">icon Other 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation2">icon Home</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="items">icon Default 2</div>
        <div class="items">icon Reports 2</div>
        <div class="items">icon Other 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    background-color:silver;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    height:25px;
}

.navigation1 {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.navigation2 {
    float:right;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.navigation1::selection, .navigation2::selection { background:transparent; }
.navigation1::-moz-selection, .navigation2::-moz-selection { background:transparent; }

.navigation1:hover, .navigation2:hover {
    background-color:gray;
}

.navigation1.active, .navigation2.active {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-bottom-color:white;
    padding:4px 9px;
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.dropdown {
    display:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:24px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $('.navigation1.active, .navigation2.active').click();
    $('.navigation1').removeClass("active");
});

$('.dropdown').each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', $(this).prev().position().left);
});

$('.navigation1, .navigation2').click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings('.navigation1.active, .navigation2.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.navigation1, .navigation2').disableSelection();​
```

**The problem:**

The only problem is the menu on the right, when it's dropdown drops down, the text ends up wrapping because the dropdown is not wide enough.  How do i get the dropdown to the correct width based on the text within it, but allow it to stick out on the left side.

So basically, for the left menu, the dropdown sticks out from the right of the menu

For the right menu, the dropdown should stick out from the left of the menu.

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mnXdv/53/

Comment: you can't do that using the same dropdown class for each dropdowns, you should use separated class or id

Comment: @oshirowanen did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, however, I have another problem with the same script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563266/having-issues-with-css-overflowhidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, please check this http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/

If you see the intended result, the way to achieve it is by giving your second dropdown `div` a second class, say `second`. After that create a css class `.second {left: auto ! important; right: 0}`. You should be good then.