# Having issues with CSS overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have some script which seems to work perfectly functionality wise:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navigation1">icon Home</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="items">icon Default 1</div>
    <div class="items">icon Reports 1</div>
    <div class="items">icon Other 1</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    margin:auto;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    position: relative;
    background:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Visually though, it all goes wrong.  As you can see from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/MTESY/2/), the menu and the footer seem to be laid out incorrectly.  When I uncomment `/*overflow:hidden;*/`, visually it looks perfect, but the `.dropdown` seems to get hidden behind the `.footer`.

How do i get this to look right visually and get it to function correctly too?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the fiddle? still not getting the motto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now define your `.menu:after` **some css properties**

as like this

```
.menu:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/7/)***

### ---------

**Or** 2nd option here

**HTML**

```
<br />
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="navigation1">icon Home</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="items">icon Default 1</div>
        <div class="items">icon Reports 1</div>
        <div class="items">icon Other 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation2">icon Home</div>
    <div class="dropdown drop2">
        <div class="items">icon Default 2</div>
        <div class="items">icon Reports 2</div>
        <div class="items">icon Other 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>  // add this line here 

</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

**Css**

```
.clr{
clear:both;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/11/)***

Answer (score 2):

Add `clear:both` to footer class:

```
.footer
{
    background:#AAAAAA;
    clear:both;
}
```

It clears formatting added due to float:left or float:right to previous tags.

Comment: Just tried this, but the `.menu` seems to lose it's background color. http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/MTESY/9/

Comment: Although not sure whether this will be ideal solution but adding float:left and width:100% to .menu solves problem. Check at http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/8/

Answer (score 0):

In terms of mark up - especially as you develop this further - your footer might not immediately follow your navigation. So put a clearfix on the navigation instead. Don't rely on the footer (or any other element) which may or may not be present in your final build to do the dirty work of clearing your floats.

EDIT: Seems that Rohit Azad and myself came up with the same answer at similar times. Follow his advice.